# Get variables and options from external project

Tags: cmake

I'd like to know how to get variables and options from an external project. For example, I'm using `ExternalProject_Add` to add a library that my project depends on, the thing is that this dependency has some variables and options - some of them are on by default - I'm wondering, how to get them from my `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All commands related with `ExternalProject_Add` are executed at *build* stage, but your `CMakeLists.txt` is interpreted at *configure* stage, when external library hasn't configured yet, so its variables and options are not defined.

More general, cmake variable from the external project can be extracted in two cases:

1. External project is included into main project via `add_subdirectory`.
2. External project provides *packaging* file, which define needed variable. In that case external project should be installed before or at configuration stage of main project. You can read about packaging in CMake [tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Packaging).

Comment: I think that I will have to "clone" some options and pass through the CMAKE_ARGS with -D for the dependency. Is that a bad practice or something wrong? The thing is that I need ExternalProject as I'm doing to be downloading the dependency.

Comment: Fine-grained configuration of the external project is perfectly OK. If you can decide your problem in such way, just do it. No need to worry about other possibilities.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, why you used the term "fine-grained" in this case? Thanks.

Comment: By this term I meant "precise, detailed". Probably, it is inappropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

I parse for answer a question similar.

This work for me:

```
  set(ZIP_DEP ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/httpserver.zip)
  if(NOT EXISTS ${ZIP_DEP})
    file(DOWNLOAD https://github.com/d3roch4/httpserver/archive/master.zip 
  ${ZIP_DEP})
    execute_process(COMMAND unzip -o ${ZIP_DEP}
                  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
                  RESULT_VARIABLE rv
    )
    if(NOT rv EQUAL 0)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "error: extract of '${ZIP_DEP}' failed")
    endif()
  endif()
  add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/httpserver-master)
```

Comment: and use `${httpserver_INCLUDE}` for include and `${httpserver_LIBS}` for link